# Contradiction of Probability: Probability vs Density?

Tags: probability

In the context of Bayesian Statistics, **we are interested in estimating the Posterior Distribution** based on an observed sample (i.e. Likelihood Function) and a Prior Probability Distribution Function.

We usually express this relationship as  follows: $$p(\theta \mid x) = \frac{p(x \mid \theta)p(\theta)}{\int_{\Theta} p(x \mid \theta)p(\theta) d\theta}$$

- $p(\theta \mid x)$ is the posterior distribution
- $p(x \mid \theta)$ is the likelihood
- $p(\theta)$ is the prior distribution
- $\int_{\Theta} p(x \mid \theta)p(\theta) d\theta$ is the normalizing constant to ensure that the sum of all possible values of the posterior is 1.

Once we have defined this relationship - we now become interested in knowing how we can use this Posterior Distribution to answer different questions.

**A popular way to use this Posterior Distribution is to take its Expected Value** (this is also called the "Bayes Estimator" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator). We define the Expected Value of the Posterior Distribution as follows :

$$\hat{\theta}(x) = \mathbb{E}[\theta \mid x] = \int_{\Theta} \theta p(\theta \mid x) d\theta$$

However, in most applications, it is very difficult to determine a closed-form solution to this integral. Therefore, we have to resort to using some algorithm (e.g. Metropolis-Hastings) to take random samples from this Posterior Distribution.

Once we have taken a set of random samples from this Posterior Distribution (e.g. 5000 samples) - we can now use these samples to calculate the Expected Value (i.e. Bayes Estimator).  **Here is where I am confused:**

- When dealing with a Discrete Probability Distribution Function - the Expected Value is equal to the probability of obtaining each "event" multiplied by the "value of each event"
- Initially, I had thought that Expected Value of the Posterior Distribution would simply be the average of all random samples generated from the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm
- However, I read that to calculate the Expected Value of the Posterior Distribution (a Continuous Probability Distribution Function) based on random samples generated from the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm - we take take each individual sample (e.g. x1), evaluate the Density of Posterior Distribution at this individual sample (e.g. Posterior(x1)), and then take the weighted averages.

**My Question:**

- But would this not be conflating the concept of Probability and Density? I had thought that for Continuous Probability Distribution Functions, the probability of observing any single point (by definition) is 0? **If this is all true - how are we supposed to calculated the Expected Value of the Posterior Distribution?**
- Our prof said that the "Expected Value of the Posterior Distribution" ("Bayes Estimator") is the same as the optimal solution for $$\mathbb{E}[(\hat{\theta}(x) - \theta)^2]$$ but he never actually explained why this is true. Are we supposed to prove this or is this simply a definition by first principle?

Thanks!

Comment: For your second question, yes, you can prove it; try differentiating by $\hat \theta$.

Comment: When sampling on a finite machine like a computer, continuous distributions are essentially approximated as discrete distributions, where the probability for a sample is its probability density times the width of its corresponding bin (or some other way to calculate the probability)

Comment: Where did you read this? Can you link to (a free version of) the text or quote it verbatim? It sounds like this might be due to a misunderstanding, so it's important to know what exactly you read.